# Axios call to laravel backend in nuxt.js

Tags: php, laravel, nuxt.js

I am trying to get a laravel-nuxt project running. I am stuck with creating route calls to my laravel backend using axios async call to serve up data to my nuxt frontend before loading the page.

I am constantly getting getting a 404 with my current laravel-nuxt setup even though I have the route defined in api.php.

I am using this as a template for the project and I have not changed anything in that template yet:
https://github.com/cretueusebiu/laravel-nuxt

So my frontend call is this here:

```
async asyncData ({ $axios }) {
  if (process.server) {
    return $axios.$get('/api/data')
    .then((res) => {
      this.data = res.data;
    })
  }
}
```

And my backend route is defined as follows in api.php:

```
Route::get('/data', 'HomeController@index');
```

It always gives me a 404, is there something missing that I should be aware of?

Comment: Do you have Laravel Telescope installed? If yes, then you can see which path the request calls.

Comment: No, I have not, I will give it a try

Comment: @Benny I have followed the github structure that you have mentioned, are all routes not working or else only this route.

Comment: Since you have not change anything in the structure. I suggest you to follow the readme and here what I found from there. **This project uses router-module, so you have to add the routes manually in client/router.js**

Answer (score 0):

According to the Readme in the Github project you have mentioned, you have to add your routes manually to

> client/router.js

Read this line under **Notes** and follow the structure well you'll be able to avoid this.

> This project uses router-module, so you have to add the routes
>   manually in client/router.js.

hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I have seen that and tried using router-module, but how do I define getting a resource instead of a page? 

I have this here defined to get to my home page:
{ path: '/', name: 'Home', component: Home },

Now I want to pull data to that component but this here doesn't work:
{ path: '/api/data', name: '', component: null },

Comment: You have both front end and backend in the same project?

Comment: If so, declare your route in **web.php** as you declared in **api.php** and remove the route from **api.php**. You may have to  change this route, `/api/data` to `/data` in axios call and remember to revert any other changes also. I think this should work. I have worked with vue and laravel in the same project, this approach work for me.

Comment: Thats exactly the point, I am already using vue and laravel in my current project and it works fine defining the route (as you described) in web.php but now with this nuxt.js and vue-router project the construct seems to be completely different or I am simply not understanding how to reach laravel through this nuxt project ...., to me it does not seem that vue-router is meant to be calling laravel backend, so how do I reach laravel backend?

Comment: ooh, @Benny then what about reporting an issue in github repo then you'll definitely get help to solve this. Go to the above repo and make a issue, I think repo contributors may have a good solution.